# How to parse json and populate gridview with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static List<Employee> GetData()
    {

        List<Employee> oEmployee = new List<Employee>
        {
               new Employee("Arijit","Accounts",23000,'01/01/2001'),
               new Employee("Tridip","Sales",15000,'01/01/2005'),
               new Employee("Dibyendu","IT",16000,'01/01/2002'),
               new Employee("Somjit","TAX",12000,'01/01/2012'),
               new Employee("Amit","Purchase",13000,'01/01/2010'),

        };
        return oEmployee;

    }
```

We have class called employee it has some property like

```
Name  string
DepartmentName string
Salary double
JoinDate datetime
```

So when i will call the `GetData`(0 function by jquery then this function return result in json format and when we get the data from client side then how could parse this json data and populate my gridview.

My gridview has 4  `<ItemTemplate>` and in each  `<ItemTemplate>` has label for hoding json data like name salary etc.

So, just please provide me the code which will parse json and populate gridview rows in loop with json data.
If 10 record return from server side then from the client side gridview will be populated with 10 records parsing json
through jquery and add rows to my gridview. please help for the client side jquery script will will parse json and populate gridview.......thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you better to use a feature called "JQuery Templates".
more information with a good example can be found here

http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2010/12/13/jquery-templates-in-asp-net-introduction.aspx

and here is a more of an advanced example: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/05/03/using-jquery-with-client-side-data-binding-templates.aspx

Answer (score 3):

you can use jquery templates.This will be a help http://www.borismoore.com/2010/09/introducing-jquery-templates-1-first.html

Comment: @R0MANARMY: no you are wrong, check the question again. "_parsing json through jquery_" in the line before last.

Comment: I don't think so. He wants to populate grid by jquery in client side  by phrasing json objects